# Logic Apps Connector for Sitecore

Tags: sitecore, azure-logic-apps

Is there a Logic Apps connector for Sitecore in the pipeline.  I looked at the [list of connectors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-salesforce) and didn't see one for Sitecore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this [document](https://docs-partners.stylelabs.com/content/integrations/azure-components/logic-apps/getting-started.html) is about the sitecore related to azure logic app, you can refer to this [connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/marketingcontenthub/) in logic app.